# Delete object Coredata

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have a project that uses coredata and i am attmepting to delete from what i have stored. But i keep getting this error.

```
An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts.
```

I looked at what apple had to say and from what i can tell i have it correct, but something is still off. Any suggestions? Thx!

```
for (UserNumber *info in pinNumberArray) {

        NSSet *time = [[NSSet alloc] initWithSet:info.Times];

        for (ErgTimes *ergTimes in time){

            NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:ergTimes.Twok, nil];
            NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
            [managedObjectContext deleteObject:eventToDelete];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, it's possibly that you've got your objects, context and threads mixed up. `NSManagedObjectContext` isn't thread safe. To delete an object from a context, you need to have fetched the object "into" the context first, and I guess your managed object was fetched by a different MOC. Without seeing more code I can't tell.

However, there is a relatively easy fix. In your for loop, do this instead

```
for (ErgTimes *ergTimes in time){
    NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:ergTimes.Twok, nil];
    NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [managedObjectContext objectWithID:[[temp objectAtIndex:0] objectID]];
    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:eventToDelete];
}
```

What this does is get the object in the MOC your currently using using its objectID which is thread-safe.

Comment: When i try that i get the following error -[NSCFNumber objectID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaa004f0. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure what's in your array, assumed it to be an NSManagedObject (or subclass). You need to get the objectID from your NSManagedObject and pass that as the argument to the MOC, which will return you the same managed object, but in your current context, which you can then delete. From your original question, what is the ErgTimes class, and it's Twok property?

Comment: Oh, sorry so, you just need to call [managedObjectContext deleteObject:[managedObjectContext objectWithID:[info objectID]]];

Comment: ErgTimes is a NSManagesObject, and TwoK is a float attribute inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same `NSManagedObjectContext` you used to fetch the objects to delete them. Easiest solution: use the managedObjectContext associated to each object to delete it. Like this:

```
for (UserNumber *info in pinNumberArray) {

    NSSet *time = [[NSSet alloc] initWithSet:info.Times];

    for (ErgTimes *ergTimes in time){

        NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:ergTimes.Twok, nil];
        NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
        [eventToDelete.managedObjectContext deleteObject:eventToDelete];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how i fetch the objects, can you see any problems with this?  NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UserNumber" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];
 
NSSortDescriptor *pinNumbers = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"PIN" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:pinNumbers];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];